# bind mvc checkbox to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, html-helper

Trying to bind an mvc helper checkbox with jquery to a javascript function and that function will do something based on the fact that it is checked or not.

**PART 1: How do you successfully bind the checkbox to a click or change event?**

**PART 2: How do you check the checkbox for checked or not?**

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Immediate)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Immediate, new {id = "chkImmediate" })
</div>
```

My attempt at binding:

```
$("#chkImmediate").click(clickEvent());

function clickEvent() {
        alert($("#chkImmediate").checked); //want it to show true/false
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the entire contents of the `<script>` the above JavaScript is in.

Comment: use change event not click event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assumming the id of the checkbox is correct, you can bind the event using jQuery like this:

```
$("#chkImmediate").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        alert('It's checked!!');
    } else {
        alert('It's not checked!!');
    }
});
```

Comment: This got me close. Thanks. What I ended up doing was this 
       $(function () {
            $('#chkImmediate').change(function () {
                var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
                clickEvent(checked);
            });
        });